# Trying to hide Highchart with Bootstrap (hidden-xs) gives some strange results

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts, responsive-design

I have two highcharts charts, one with only two columns that I'd like displayed on mobile devices, and one with several that I feel is OK for tablets and desktops. Problem is, highcharts doesn't seem to see it that way.

Using `hidden-xs` and `visible-xs` respectively to display `@chart` and `@chart_mobile` inside my view seems to only show one chart or the other the whole time.

Here's my code.

The view:

```
<div class="hidden-xs">
<%= high_chart("some_id", @chart) %>
</div>
<div class="visible-xs">
  <%= high_chart("some_id", @chart_mobile) %>
</div>
```

**The controller:**
**Desktop Chart**

```
  @chart = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
  f.title(:text => "Newsletter Reach")
  f.xAxis(:categories => ["Last Month", "Two Weeks Ago", "Last Week", "This Week"])
  f.series(:name => "Deliveries", :yAxis => 0, :data => [@stats_last_month["delivered"], @stats_this_month_two_weeks["delivered"], @stats_last_week["delivered"], @stats_this_week["delivered"]])
  f.series(:name => "Bounces", :yAxis => 0, :data => [@stats_last_month["bounces"], @stats_this_month_two_weeks["bounces"], @stats_last_week["bounces"], @stats_this_week["bounces"]])
  f.series(:name => "Spam Reports", :yAxis => 0, :data => [@stats_last_month["spamreports"], @stats_this_month_two_weeks["spamreports"], @stats_last_week["spamreports"], @stats_this_week["spamreports"]])
  f.series(:name => "Opens", :yAxis => 0, :data => [@stats_last_month["opens"], @stats_this_month_two_weeks["opens"], @stats_last_week["opens"], @stats_this_week["opens"]])


  f.yAxis [
    {:title => {:text => "Number of Emails", :margin => 10} },
  ]

  f.legend(:align => 'right', :verticalAlign => 'top', :y => 20, :x => -10, :layout => 'vertical',)
  f.chart({:defaultSeriesType=>"column"})
end
```

**Mobile Chart:**

```
  @chart_mobile = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
  f.title(:text => "Newsletter Reach Mobile")
  f.xAxis(:categories => ["Last Month", "This Week"])
  f.series(:name => "Deliveries", :yAxis => 0, :data => [@stats_last_month["delivered"], @stats_this_week["delivered"]])
  f.series(:name => "Bounces", :yAxis => 0, :data => [@stats_last_month["bounces"], @stats_this_week["bounces"]])
  f.series(:name => "Spam Reports", :yAxis => 0, :data => [@stats_last_month["spamreports"], @stats_this_week["spamreports"]])
  f.series(:name => "Opens", :yAxis => 0, :data => [@stats_last_month["opens"], @stats_this_week["opens"]])


  f.yAxis [
    {:title => {:text => "Number of Emails", :margin => 10} },
  ]

  f.legend(:align => 'right', :verticalAlign => 'top', :y => 20, :x => -10, :layout => 'vertical',)
  f.chart({:defaultSeriesType=>"column"})
end
```

Am I doing something with my naming that's confusing Highcharts or my View?

Answer (score 0):

> **SOLVED:**

I needed to give the two charts different `id`'s in my view. Resulting code:

```
<div class="hidden-xs">
<%= high_chart("some_id", @chart) %>
</div>
<div class="visible-xs">
  <%= high_chart("another_id", @chart_mobile) %>
</div>
```